# sfDoctrineGuardPlugin and admin filters

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have an admin that uses `sfDoctrineGuardPlugin`. I also have another table, `sf_guard_user_profile`, that extends the `sf_guard_user` table, to include more fields, such as address, age etc

My problem is, I am embedding the profile (`sf_guard_user_profile`) information into the `sf_guard_user` record when viewing the records in the admin generated module. This works fine, but I'd like to then be able to use some of the filters from the `sf_guard_user_profile` table.

I have tried to add these into the `generator.yml` file, but I this throws an error

generator.yml

```
...................

  filter:
    display: [username, email_address, address_1, is_active ]

Widget "address_1" does not exist.
```

address_1 is a field in `sf_guard_user_profile`

Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I had to do a little bit of work in the `sfGuardUserFormFilter` class,

```
  $this->widgetSchema['age'] =  new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(
      'label' => 'Age'
  ));

  //Type of validator for filter
  $this->validatorSchema['age'] = new sfValidatorPass(array ('required' => false));

public function getFields()
{
  $fields = parent::getFields();
  $fields['age'] = 'age';
  return $fields;
}


public function addAgeColumnQuery($query, $field, $value)
{
     $rootAlias = $query->getRootAlias();

     $query->where('p.age LIKE ?', '%'.$value.'%');

     //remember to return the $query!
     return $query;
}
```

I could then use the `age` field in the `generator.yml` file.

Thanks